Examples of nontrivial morphism between simple bundles but not isomorphism
We know stable bundles have a good property:

If $f: E\longrightarrow E'$ is a nontrivial morphism where $E,E'$ have the same rank and degree, then $f$ must be an isomorphism.

I'm wondering does this property hold for simple bundles? If not, are there any counter-examples? i.e, find two simple bundles $E,E'$ of same rank and degree but there exists a non-trivial morphism $f$ between them which is not isomorphic.

This property is the key to the Hausdorff property of the moduli space of stable bundles, say $\mathcal{M}^s_{X}(n,d)$, where $n$ is the rank, $d$ is the degree and $X$ is a genus $g$ curve. Since for stable bundles $E_1,E_0$, if $\{E_t\}$ is a family of isomorphism classes of $E_1$ which deforms to $E_0$, then it defines a nontrivial morphism $E_1\longrightarrow E_0$, hence it must be isomorphism, that eliminates the jumping and non-Hausdorff phenomenon.
But for simple bundles, It was showed in Remark 12.3 of Narasimhan-Seshadri's paper that the moduli space $\mathcal{M}^{\text{sim}}_{X}(2,1)$ of rank 2 degree 1 simple bundles over a genus 3 curve $X$ is not Hausdorff, so I think a counter-example of the above property may occur in this case.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus 2, and let $L,M$ be two nonisomorphic line bundles of degree zero. Consider nontrivial extensions $L\to E \to M$ and $M \to E' \to L$ (these exists by the nonvanishing of the corresponding Ext groups, which can be seen using Riemann Roch). Then I believe that both $E$ and $E'$ are simple rank 2 bundles of degree 0, but the composition $E\to M \to E'$ is a nonzero morphism which is not an isomorphism.
